# hgignore glob works differently to hgstatus glob

Tags: python, mercurial, kml

I have a folder set up like the following:

- project/latest_kml/file.kml
- project/.hgignore
- project/.hg/...

My .hgignore file looks like this:

```html
syntax: glob
*.kml
*.kmz
**nohup.out
log/**
```

After a bit of googling I found out that I should have used "**.kml'
What I am not understanding is why *.kml is ignoring the .kml files. If I add a new .kml file to the latest_kml folder it doesn't get added when I run addremove, or appear in hg status.

If I remove the *.kml line then hg status shows the new .kml file.

**The confusing part:** If I remove the '*.kml' line from .hgignore and run hg status 'glob:**.kml' it shows the new kml file that was added to project/latest_kml/. If I instead use hg status 'glob:*.kml', it shows nothing.

What is the cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg help patterns` states clearly

> Globs are rooted at     the current directory; a glob such as "*.c" will only match files in the
>   current directory ending with ".c".
>
> The supported glob syntax extensions are "**" to match any string across path separators
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  glob:*.c       any name ending in ".c" in the current directory
>  *.c            any name ending in ".c" in the current directory
>  **.c           any name ending in ".c" in any subdirectory of the
>                 current directory including itself.
> ```

Comment: Exactly. So that doesn't explain why somehow *.kml in the hgignore file is ignoring .kml files in a sub-directory. It shouldn't be behaving like that.

Comment: @Smills - just because patterns in (*only* !!!) `.hgignore` are **not rooted**, contrary to all other patterns (used by you in command-line)

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks, I hadn't seen mention of the .hgignore not being rooted.